# Как сделать, чтобы переменная изменяла свое значение только при нажатой клавише?

Tags: переменные, opengl

Как сделать, чтобы переменная изменяла свое значение только при нажатой клавише : вверх, вниз, влево, вправо?
Например у мышки это реализовано так:

```
bool down = false;

void mouse(int button, int state, int ax, int ay)
{

    down = state == GLUT_DOWN;
}
```

У меня старая версия `opengl 2`.

Answer (score 1):

glutKeyboardUpFunc есть? Если нет, то — никак, нужно самостоятельно обрабатывать WinApi сообщения.